# Capture and sort output of command in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, capture

To re-format some disks, I am using the following script:

```
for i in {1..7};
do
echo -e "\e[33mFormat Disk: /dev/sg$i"
echo -e "\e[39m---------------------------"
sg_format -v --format --size=512 /dev/sg$i &
done
```

the command `sg_format` can be started in such way that all 7 disks are formatted in parallel, however the output on the console is now a mess when the progress (in %) of the formatting process is reported.

I could serialize instead but then the format of the (hdd) disks would take a very long time.
Is there a simple way to capture the progress of each running `sg_format` and tidy his up like this:

```
echo "status sg_format on disk /dev/sg$i"
--> output progress from sg_format
```

Comment: You can redirect each sg_format to its own tempfile, and while you wait for all sg_formats to complete, you erase previous output and `cat` all the tempfiles. Actually I'm not sure if this will work, because you'd be printing out files as they're being written to

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about something like this, but it's beyond my knowledge oof bash scripting.

Answer (score 0):

An option would be to start them in separate `xterms`

```
xterm -e "sg_format -v --format --size=512 /dev/sg$i; sleep 30 &
```

Comment: the Linux I am using doesn't have xterm available, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Not perfect, but with my limited bash knowledge an acceptable solution:

```
sgFormatCount=0
sgFormatCount=$(pgrep sg_format | wc -l)


if [ $sgFormatCount = 0 ]
then
  for i in {1..7};
   do
    sg_format --format --size=512 /dev/sg$i &
  done
fi
```

Once sg_format has started on all disks, monitor the running progress:

```
while true;
 do
  for i in {1..7};
   do 
    sg_format -v  /dev/sg$i
  done
 sleep 60
done
```